# if condition when a div has content do this else do that

Tags: php, wordpress

I have here a script

```
<div>
<?php 
echo '<strong>Other information</strong><br />';
$myname = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'acidity_gl', true); if ( $myname ) { echo 'Acidity: ' . $myname . '<br />'; }
$myname = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'winePh', true); if ( $myname ) { echo 'Wine PH: ' . $myname . '<br />'; }
$myname = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'residual_sugar_gl', true); if ( $myname ) { echo 'Residual Sugar gl: ' . $myname . '<br />'; }
?>
</div>
```

I would like to add a condition when if $myname has a value then display the DIV but when there is no value on those 3 $myname then dont display DIV

Comment: You have to place the condition outside of your DIV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php
    $myname=array();
    $name = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'acidity_gl', true);
    if ( !empty($name) ) { 
        $myname[] = 'Acidity: ' . $name ; 
    }
    $name = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'winePh', true);
    if ( !empty($name) ) { 
        $myname[] = 'Wine PH: ' . $name ; 
    }
    $name = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'residual_sugar_gl', true);
    if ( !empty($name) ) { 
        $myname[] = 'Residual Sugar gl: ' . $name; 
    }
    if(!empty($myname))
    {
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<strong>Other information</strong><br />';
        echo implode('<br />',$myname);
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!empty ( $myname ))
{
// write your code for DIV here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<?php
if(!empty($my_name)){
?>
<div>DIV Content here</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Or

```
<?php
if(!empty($my_name)){
 echo '<div>DIV Content here</div>';
}
?>
```